# VSC python script execution has changed behavior

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I have VSC and Anaconda installed on my computer, At first VSC ran all my python scripts correctly using the command `python {file location}`. Now it executes my python scripts using the command `conda run -n ML --no-capture-output --live-stream python {file location}`.

I want it to return to its previous behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use conda run for conda environments for running python files and
> installing modules. ([#18479](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18479))

[changelog](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/ms-python.python/changelog)(28 February 2022).

You can install the older version of the Python Extension 1 month ago to roll back. But it's suggested to get used to it.